# Layout animation in android is not working properly

Tags: android, layout, android-animation

I want to slide my layout from top to bottom and remain visible. below is the code which do layout from bottom to top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="400"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fromYDelta="100%p"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-100%"android:duration="1000"/>   
</set>
```